# Macro to adjust an entire row in an Excel table at once

Tags: vba, excel

I need a way to programatically adjust an entire row in an excel table based on the ActiveCell, irrespective of what table it's in or where the table is. I was using

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows(ActiveCell.Row - 1).Range.Select
Selection.Style = "Good"
```

but upon shifting the table down five rows, it now applies the action down a further five rows from the ActiveCell.

I've tried finding a way to replace the `- 1` with some sort of `- .HeaderRowRange.Row` but nothing happens when I activate the macro.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.ListObject(1)` is going to refer to the same table no matter where your cursor is. I'm inferring that you only have one table per sheet, but that might be throwing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `ActiveCell.ListObject` property. This makes it more flexible, e.g., if there's two tables in a worksheet:

```
Sub FormatActiveTableRow()
Dim lo As Excel.ListObject

Set lo = ActiveCell.ListObject
If Not lo Is Nothing Then
    Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, lo.Range).Style = "Good"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I know an answer was already accepted, but I wrote this earlier today. My phone-code-formatting skills aren't good though. I like the question and thought it might still be of interest.

Comment: Yours is a useful point. Rather than refer to the table directly, it can be referenced based on the activecell's position. Vote up.

Comment: In the interest of the community and having the most useful answer (in general) easier to find, I've re-accepted. @user3561813 had an answer that worked in my case, but yours will work in more situations.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem correctly, try using the following code and report back:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows(ActiveCell.Row - ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange.Row).Range.Select
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I tried that earlier, but I must have had a typo or something because it threw a "method not available" error.